# Low level Bluetooth Programming in C++

Tags: c++, bluetooth, low-level-api

I need a library (or API, ...) to do some low level Bluetooth programming using C++. Any reference or rich link will be great!

And i prefer to work in linux based opreration systems...

Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.bluez.org/ for Linux

http://inthehand.com/content/32feet.aspx for Windows